# "Invalid snapshot time" error without table decorator usage

Tags: google-bigquery

We got an error that `{"message":"Invalid snapshot time 1472342794519, unable to read before 1472342794785","reason":"invalid"}`. [Other QA](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=81) describes that such an error happens when table decorators' parameters are invalid, however, our query does not have table decorators.

The query uses `TABLE_DATE_RANGE`, but its arguments are date timestamp, so the lower digits must be 0s, not like that in the above error.

Retrying the same query succeeded.

I can provide the job ID, but because it includes internal information of our company. I apologize that I cannot directly write it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables that the TABLE_DATE_RANGE wildcard evaluates to are resolved as of the time of the start of the query. Looking at the timestamps, it looks like the table was deleted right after the job started execution. This causes the table resolution to throw that error.

Comment: I see. So the smartest solution which users can take is to retry for such errors, right?